# Do bounties actually work?

Tags: discussion, bounties, statistics

I've been on these sites for several years now, and I've asked a bunch of questions. I've put out a few bounties, however, I don't believe that I've ever actually awarded one. I'm not sure that I've ever had anyone ANSWER a question with a bounty on it.

Are there statistics on how effective bounties are to get better/more answers for questions?

Comment: In my experience, bounties work. I'm not sure about data though, you could try SEDe.

Comment: My anecdotal evidence? Not really..